# How can I improve the display of units in sympy.physics.units in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython, sympy, physics

Units from sympy.physics.units are displayed in a strange way in Jupyter Notebook ([see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OZRa.png)).

I'm working with the code below where I want to calculate the value of lambda based on the other variables U, R and omega:

```
import sympy as sp
import sympy.physics.units as u
from IPython.display import display
U, R, omega, lam = sp.symbols('U R omega lambda')

# Pretending to have some known values for a problem
known = {R : 80 * u.m,
         omega : 1.01 * (1/u.s),
         U: 10 * (u.m/u.s)}

display(known[R], known[omega], known[U])
```

However, my units are not displayed in a nice way e.g. known[U] is displayed as (10/s)*m instead
of 10*(m/s).

I have tried to use 'UnevaluatedExpr' which improves the results, but it is quite tedious to use:

```
# Trying with UnevaluatedExpr
known = {R : 80 * u.m,
          omega : 1.01 * sp.UnevaluatedExpr(1/u.s),
          U : 10 * sp.UnevaluatedExpr(u.m/u.s)}
display(known[R], known[omega], known[U])
```

The problem becomes even worse when I try to continue with my calculations

```
# Define equation
eq1 = sp.Eq(lam, omega*R/U)

# Calculate lambda using the known values and display the result
display(eq1.rhs.subs(known))
```

The above displays 8.08*1/s*(m/s)**(-1)*m instead of the expected (80m*1.01*1/s)/(10m/s)